# Google Map Embed API Key not working

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-maps-embed

I am trying to add google maps Embed API to my site. I keep getting this error:

"The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key."

The API key is correct. I have Static Map turned on. Two of the most common trouble shots.

Code is formatted as follows:

```
  <iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA">
</iframe>
```

I put the < infront of iframe in my code. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Any one have any suggesions?

Answer (score 2):

Static Maps and the Embed API are different things and controlled differently.  Do what the message suggests (in its round about way) and turn on the Embed API in the [Google API console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

- [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/)
- [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

Answer (score 1):

I found that the placeholder in Google's *HTTP referrers* inputs of `<https (or) http>://*.example.com/*` are misleading, because it suggests that the whole `<https (or) http>` thing is parsed as some actual "or" statement.  In reality, **it is not**.

You must specify your protocol exactly, such as `https://*.example.com`.  And, if you need support for both protocols, you must specify them as unique rows.

Hope that helps someone out there.